# Insert formatted values from DataGridView to DataBase

Tags: c#, datagridview

My cell formatting functions is like this :

```
private void dataGridViewCND_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            if (e.Value.ToString().Contains("S010"))
            {
                e.Value = "BE";
            }
            else if (e.Value.ToString().Contains("S011"))
            {
                    e.Value = "BI";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I update, the non formatted values are inserted in my database instead of the formatted ones.

Edit : 
This is the code I insert in my database with :

```
private void buttonEnregistrer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridViewCND.EndEdit();
    dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
    DataBind();
}
```

This is my DataBind() function

```
private void DataBind()
{
    dataGridViewCND.DataSource = null;
    dataTable.Clear();
    string query = "SELECT xxxxxxxxxxxx FROM xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStringLocal);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = query;
    dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    bindingSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = dataTable };
    dataGridViewCND.DataSource = bindingSource;
}
```

Comment: can you show the code which you are using to insert into database

Comment: @Lucifer I edited my post

Comment: are you binding the data-source of datagridview with data-table?

Comment: @Lucifer I edited my post again

Comment: @A.Petit that is because, you are formatting data grid view not data source! added answer. try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `dataGridViewCND_CellFormatting` method, you are actually formatting values which are going to be displayed on grid view.

This actually doesn't change values in your data source (here `dataTable`). So data source is holding unformulated data only.

So when you query into database to update it with values of `dataTable`, database too doesn't get updated with formatted data.

You need to keep updating your `dataTable` too when you are formatting values on data grid view.

update, `dataGridViewCND_CellFormatting` like below.

```
private void dataGridViewCND_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
  {
      if (e.Value != null)
       {
          if (e.Value.ToString().Contains("S010"))
          {
              dataTable.Rows[e.ColumnIndex][e.RowIndex] = "BE";
              e.Value = "BE";
          }
          else if (e.Value.ToString().Contains("S011"))
          {
              dataTable.Rows[e.ColumnIndex][e.RowIndex] = "BI";
              e.Value = "BI";
          }
      }
  }
}
```